# AVPlayer m3u8 video end issue

Tags: swift, avplayer, m3u8

I was using this code to do something after video finish.

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(stopedPlaying), name: NSNotification.Name.AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime, object: nil)
```

This was working with mp4 videos. But because they are more than 10mins, I start to use m3u8 format. But this part of code does not work anymore. Any idea would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to add the object for which you should observe the change. Try adding the `playerItem` object like in the code below.

```
  NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: #selector(stopedPlaying), 
  name: AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification, 
  object: destination.player!.currentItem)
```

Comment: Sorry mate. But it is the same even I add the object. And as I mentioned, that is working with mp4.

Comment: It is working for me with m3u8 streaming. Can you share some more code?

Comment: My app have live streaming in m3u8 format, but could not get the end notification. Did any of you guys have the solution for it?

Comment: I am also facing the same issue, anyone, please help